# Find critical points, extremes, maximums and minimums

Tags: calculus

I've been working on this problem and i got stuck.

Let $f(x,y)=(x-1)^2 - y^3 + 3y^2$. The domain of the function is D

$D = {(x,y): y^2 \leq x \leq 4 }  $

Find the minimums and maximums.
Are there any maximum or minimum point in the boundary of D?
Are there any maximum or minimum point in the interior of the set D?

I found 2 critical points in the interior of the set D:
$P_{1}= (1,0)$ and $ P_{2}=(1,2)$
But i don't know how to define the minimum or maximums points in the boundary . I have 3 ways to define the boundary : $ y = -\sqrt{x}$ ;  $ y = \sqrt{x}$  ; $(4,y)$.
But then i got stuck. How should i proceed?
Another question is : is (1,2) in D? $  y^{2}\leq x $ and  $ 2^{2}\nleqslant 1$, so $(1,2)\notin D$  but i was not sure about it.

Comment: I think it's best to start from drawing the region $D$ on x-y plane. Then it will be easy to see whether $(x,y)=(1, 2)$ is in $D$.